# Play Framework 2 Set form input class

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I've read through documentation at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers and searched for the solution, but i can't figure out.

I can't imagine that you have to create custom field constructor just to set the class.

**How to set field class with default field constructor?**

Thanks for help!

Edit:
If there is a way to set other (custom attributes, like data-*) attr-s to the element w/ default constructor that would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is right there in the documentation you linked to.

I changed the `id` to `class`.

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit, 'class -> "my-class") {

}
```

Or

```
@helper.inputText(myForm("username"), 'class -> "my-class", 'size -> 30)
```

---

Using symbols with hyphens does not work out-of-the-box.

Simplest solution is to create a symbol like this:

```
@helper.inputText(myForm("username"), Symbol("data-m-dec") -> "4", 'size -> 30)
```

Comment: could you tell me how can i use data attr.s like 'data-m-dec -> "4"? when i use - char in attr's name i get an error